# Can different subclass values be reflect in inherited methods?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, subclass

I'm trying to create a program to help me learn the Inheritance with Java. However, in this process, I discovered a problem with what I thought I had learned.

The program is simple. I have a superclass called *Gun* and a subclass called *M1911*. The idea of this program is just to show to me that you don't have to repeat methods like the one I made too called `shoot()`. However, here is the problem. I wanted `shoot()` to print a message to the console saying

```
"GunModel: Pew, pew!"
```

. GunModel and `shoot()` being defined in Gun and the M1911 subclass to have a different value than the initial value inherited from *Gun*. This would mean if *M1911* had a GunModel == "M1911", the method `shoot()` would reflect that by printing

```
"M1911: Pew, pew!"
```

That all (obviously?) didn't work because to me it looks like the value of within subclass has no influence on inherited methods. So, why is that if True. Also, what is the Goal of inheritance I'm missing? It seems like its more than just avoiding repetition.

Edit: Heres my code I should have given first.

```
public class Gun {  
    protected String GunModel;
    public void shoot() {
        System.out.println(GunModel + ": Pew, pew!");
    }
}

public class M1911 extends Gun {
    public String GunModel = "M1911";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation of what you're trying to achieve.  Can you include the code you tried?  It's hard to know where you went wrong otherwise.  Thanks!

Comment: It should work if your shoot method is defined as getGunModel() + "Pew, pew!" and you have an abstract getGunModel method implemented by M1911 or whatever

Comment: Hi, my first post sorry. Bound to make a few mistakes even though I'm trying to becareful!

Comment: Gun.java...
public class Gun { 
 protected String GunModel;
 public void shoot() {
  System.out.println(GunModel + ": Pew, pew!");
 }
}


M1911.java....
public class M1911 extends Gun {
 public GunModel = "M1911";
}

"Edit, sorry for no formatting, really new to all this".

Comment: Java fields cannot be overriden, but methods can. Use a getter for the GunModel field. Also, you might want to editi your question instead of putting all your code in a comment

Comment: Oh, right. Wouldn't that change it for any classes thereafter if I extend gun to more classes?

Edit: I should say, I thought inheritance could be used so that each subclass calls it in a different way depending on its variables. But maybe another concept i haven't learn't yet deals with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what I got for your code (from the unformatted comment):

```
public class Gun 
{ protected String GunModel; 
  public void shoot() 
  { System.out.println(GunModel + ": Pew, pew!"); 
  } 
} 

public class M1911 extends Gun 
{ 
  public GunModel = "M1911"; 
}
```

As was pointed out by 'user' in comments, "GunModel" cannot be overridden, so what you have here are two different variables with the same name.

Here is what you could do:

```
public class Gun 
{ 
  protected String GunModel = "Gun"; 
  public void shoot() 
  { System.out.println(GunModel + ": Pew, pew!"); 
  } 
} 

public class M1911 extends Gun 
{ 
  public M1911()
  {
    GunModel = "M1911";
  }
}
```

After that, if someone executes `gunVariable = new M1911()` and `gunVariable.shoot()`, it will print "M1911: Pew, pew!".

There are also other ways to do this -- GunModel could be private, and be accessed by getter and setter methods instead of directly.

A word about the Java code: by convention, classes start with capital letters and variables start with lowercase letters. Using this convention, which is pretty universally followed, your variable would be spelled "gunModel" instead of "GunModel"; an advantage of this is that it is easy to tell which things are variables and which things are classes. And one tells which things starting with lowercase are methods by seeing that they have parens after them.

Comment: This is for sure what I was looking for! Why does it have to be in what looks like a constructor? If I may ask.

Also, thanks! I had actually rewritten the code again for this question because I made some changes in the original project trying to figure more stuff out. I'm aware of the naming conventions just a mistake and from studying C# a moment ago. (Should I edit the original post?).

Comment: I would not edit the original post now, it isn't THAT important (besides, it makes my comment puzzling). It doesn't HAVE to be in the constructor, but an argument for putting it there is that you want that value in that variable from the time an instance of M1911 is created.  If someone instantiated it and immediately invoked `shoot()`, then you want the value there already. I don't know why you would put the assignment somewhere else.

Comment: Ah. Yeah, that does make sense.  Cheers, a lot for your answer and help. I got that feeling I love about programming. Learning something that seemed hard but is now relatively easy.

Comment: One more point of order, this one about StackOverflow: any answer you find useful, whether to your question or not, you can "upvote" it, and that gives a few points to the writer of that answer. For your own questions, you can *also* choose one answer that answers your question, perhaps the earliest that does if there's  more than one, and click the checkmark icon to the left of that answer -- that also gives some points to the writer. This is how writers of answers are rewarded for volunteering their time.

Comment: Sorted! I already upvoted. I had read some posts on StackOverflow and just assumed it was the top-rated comment that got marked as a solution automatically. Thanks, again!

Answer (score 2):

Individual attributes (i.e. fields) cannot be overwritten through inheritance. There are many languages where this is possible, such as C# and Python. Java, however, supports only the overwriting of methods. There are multiple ways to handle this:

1. Create a supplier method "getGunModel" that returns GunModel without referring to the field.
2. If the identity of a weapon is solely based on its name, create an enumclass `public enum Guns` with field `final private String gunName` and refer to this field in the `shoot()` method. This method must be defined in the enum context, i.e. do not redefine `shoot()` in every listed instance in the enum, but call it dynamically:

```
enum Guns {
    SOMEGUN("M1911"),
    THATGUN("AK-47");

    private final String gunName;

    private Guns(String modelName) {
        this.gunName = modelName;
    }

    public void shoot() {
        System.out.println(this.gunName + ": Pew pew!");
    }
}

// Now we can call Guns.SOMEGUN.shoot(), which will return "M1911: Pew pew!" over stdout
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

When you inherit something, you can inherit: behavior and state.
State basically cannot be overriden, in your code snippet the M1911 instance in memory will actually have 2 "slots" - one `GunModel` that came from the `Gun` class and one `GunModel` that came from `M1911` class.

Usually you don't do this in real programs.

Behavior on the other hand can be overriden. By Behavior I mean methods:

```
class Gun {
    public void shoot() {
        System.out.println("Gun : Pew, pew!");
    }
}

class M1911 extends Gun {
    public void shoot() { // overrides
        System.out.println("M1911 : Pew, pew!");
    }
}
```

Comment: But he wants to use inheritance to store a type that depends on his subclass; there might be uses for it other than the 'shoot' method. And he can do that, he just can't do it the way he tried to. I've supplied an answer that I think is closer to the original intent.

Comment: I was somewhat aware that behavior can be overwritten. But for small examples like mine that could be expanded to multiple subclasses, this didn't seem like I was gaining anything. Because I wanted inheritance to reflect changes in the parent to its children. But great to know I can do this for more one-off solutions, cheers!